# Haskell: Why is it saying my function type is off?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I wrote a little Haskell program to find the area of a triangle, primarily to practice custom types, but it keeps throwing the following error on compile:

```
areafinder.hs:7:4:
    Couldn't match expected type `Triangle' against inferred type `m b'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: putStr "Base: "
    In the expression:
        do { putStr "Base: ";
             baseStr <- getLine;
             putStr "Height: ";
             heightStr <- getLine;
             .... }
    In the definition of `getTriangle':
        getTriangle = do { putStr "Base: ";
                           baseStr <- getLine;
                           putStr "Height: ";
                           .... }
```

I'm not sure where 'm b' comes from, so I'm at a loss here. Why is it throwing this error, and what can I do to fix it? Here is my code:

```
module Main where

data Triangle = Triangle Double Double -- base, height
getTriangle :: Triangle
getTriangle = do
    putStr "Base: "
    baseStr <- getLine
    putStr "Height: "
    heightStr <- getLine
    let base = read baseStr :: Double
    let height = read heightStr :: Double
    Triangle base height

calcTriangle :: Triangle -> Double
calcTriangle (Triangle base height) = base * height

main = putStrLn ("Area = " ++ show (calcTriangle getTriangle))
```

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `getTriangle` function uses IO, so you have to put that in the function signature.

```
getTriangle :: IO Triangle
```

Also, the last line should have `return`, since it's returning a pure value inside an IO function.

```
return (Triangle base height)
```

Here are a couple extra tips: Haskell can figure out that `base` and `height` are `Double`, because you pass them to `Triangle`, so you don't need to explicitly declare them that way.  You can use `liftM` from the `Control.Monad` module to read the input and convert to `Double` in one step.

```
import Control.Monad
getTriangle :: IO Triangle
getTriangle = do
    putStr "Base: "
    base <- liftM read getLine
    putStr "Height: "
    height <- liftM read getLine
    return (Triangle base height)
```

The `main` function also appears to mix pure values with IO.  Since getTriangle is IO, you can't pass it directly to calcTriangle.  Here is a modified `main`:

```
main = do tri <- getTriangle
          putStrLn ("Area = " ++ show (calcTriangle tri))
```

As a footnote, the area of a triangle is `base * height / 2`, not `base * height`.

Finally, a more advanced Haskell programmer would probably write `getTriangle` in terms of `liftM2`, but this is just a matter of style.  Here is how I would write it:

```
prompt str = putStr (str ++ ": ") >> liftM read getLine
getTriangle = liftM2 Triangle (prompt "Base") (prompt "Height")
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! Functional programming is still a bit difficult for me, but I'm getting it. Also, I have no clue how I forgot the division in the formula. :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can drop `getTriangle :: Triangle` and by running `:t getTriangle` that the hugs/ghci prompt it will tell you what it thinks the types should be.